# Option operators with access to Option container

Tags: scala

I've got some functions (f2..fn) which take an A, and return Option[A]. This works very nicely (assuming f1:X => Option[A]) to do e.g.

```
f1(x) flatMap f2 flatMap f3
```

Now I'd like to be able to record what happens, and especially where None gets introduced. I'd like to be able to interpose a function such as:

```
log_none(m:String):Option[A] => Option[A]
```

which has the side effect of logging if None is encountered.

None of the Option functionality seems to work for this (after reading e.g. tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)

Ideally, it would then look something like:

```
f1(x) <.> log_none("f1 failed") flatMap f2 <.> log_none("f2 failed") ...
```

I can't immediately see an elegant, idiomatic way to do this - I can't see anything to put in the <.> positions.

Comment: Great answers, I like them all. I think andThen is closest to what I asked for, implicit classes will do least damage to existing code, and scalaz is probably the most correct way to go. So no idea which one to accept. I'm going to try the implicit classes and see how that works out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good case for scalaz's Validation. It's similar to Option but instead of None it gives you an error value.

Before:

```
def f1(x: Int): Option[Int]
def f2(x: Int): Option[Int]
def f2(x: Int): Option[Int]

for {
  x1 <- f1(x)
  x2 <- f2(x1)
  x3 <- f3(x2)
} yield x3
```

You can do a simple conversion with the toSuccess implicit

```
import scalaz.{Validation, Success, Failure}
import scalaz.Validation.FlatMap._
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._

def oldf1(x: Int): Option[Int]

def f1(x: Int): Validation[String, Int] = oldf1(x).toSuccess("f1 failed")
def f2(x: Int): Validation[String, Int]
def f2(x: Int): Validation[String, Int]

val validatedX3: Validation[String, Int] = for {
  x1 <- f1(x)
  x2 <- f2(x1)
  x3 <- f3(x2)
} yield x3

validatedX3 match {
  case Success(i) =>
    Some(i)
  case Failure(errStr) => 
    log(errStr)
    None
}
```

Or alternately

```
validatedX3.leftMap(log).toOption
```

You can similar things with scala Either, but it's more painful because you need to use `.toRightProjection` all over the place.

I pretend that Validation is monadic with the `Validation.FlatMap` import even though it's not, but you can use the applicative version as well to collect multiple errors if your f1,2,3 don't need sequencing. http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html

Answer (score 2):

I think `andThen` is the method you are looking for here, though it's not that pretty:

```
(f1[A] _ andThen log_none("f1 failed"))(x) flatMap (f2[A] _ andThen log_none("f2 failed")) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an implicit class:

```
scala> implicit class LogEmptyOption[A](opt: Option[A]) {
     |   def logNone(m: String): Option[A] = {
     |     if (opt.isEmpty)
     |       println(m)
     |     opt
     |   }
     | }
defined class LogEmptyOption

scala> Option.empty[String].logNone("No Such element")
```

This lets you extend (so-to-speak) the original class without actually creating a new subclass.